# Current location on Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have called `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` but it does not show my current location. Please advise.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (mMap.isMyLocationEnabled()) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    private void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enalbled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.companero, PID: 25005
                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: MyLocation layer not enabled
                                                               at maps.f.g.b(Unknown Source)
                                                               at maps.ag.t.j(Unknown Source)
                                                               at uz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:281)
                                                               at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.getMyLocation(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMyLocation(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your `GoogleMap` can sometimes take a while to load so your `Location` might be `null`.

```
if (mMap != null) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Give this a go:

```
if (mMap != null) {
    Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();

    if (myLocation != null) {
        LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
   }
}
```

If this doesn't work, you can try this also:

The Google Maps API location now works, even has listeners, you can do it using that, for example:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 16.0f));
    }
};
```

I would suggest [reading the following](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to look at this. When I use your code, other activity works well until I click on the map, it goes crashed and "Unfortunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: 06-14 21:47:50.877 6021-6573/com.companero E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companero-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companero-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

Comment: By checking the internet for the other people who encountered the same problem of yours, in updating Google Play Services to 9.0.83 or later. Try that and let me know how you go.

Comment: http://www.discuzfeed.com/code/loezsopu-android-app-is-crashing-due-to-v-googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid.html